# How to load data before rendering page without using a resolver?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have the problem that my object is not defined before rendering the page.
I want to first load my data and then render the page without using a resolver or ngIf.
Could I use LifeCycle Hooks to get this work?

My current setup:

app.component.ts

```
  onNavigateToDetailView(url: string, title: string){
     this.service.getResourceUrl(url).subscribe( 
       (data) => {
         this.service.detailedObj = data;
         console.log(data);
       } 
     );
     this.router.navigate(['detailedview/' + title]);
  }
```

Now in my `view.component.ts` I want to assign the object in my service to a variable:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.obj = this.service.obj;
}
```

In my `view.component.html` I have:

```
{{obj.text}}
```

It does now work, because as I said the object is undefined while rendering. If I would use the object in my service like that

```
{{this.service.obj.text}
```

it works but I do not want to use it.

So can I somehow wait for the data being defined and then render the page without using a Resolver or *ngIf? Is it somehow be possible with another LyfeCycle Hook instead of ngOnInit?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-21zvgm

As you see after navigating to hello.component and empty object is the output to the console. But when you click show in hello.component. the object is initialized correctly...

Comment: You have to load your data inside ngOnInit in your view.component.ts, or you subject if want to bind data between 2 different components

Comment: @AhmedE.Eldeeb Hey thank you for your answer! I know now why it does not working. Somehow after leaving the current page, the object in my service gets empty. I dont know why. I thought variables in a service are persistent

Comment: Can you explain the use case? I cant make anything of it. Lifecycle hooks will provide hooks for the stages of component and not of async operation on a service. And yes, variables in a service are persistent

Comment: If possible, add a minimal reproducible on stackblitz to have a look

Comment: I will in a moment!

Comment: While you can't use a lifecycle hook for api call, you can use the safe navigation operator {{ this.service?.obj?.text }}

Comment: @T.SunilRao I edited the project !

Comment: Checking it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your stackblitz and question, I understand, you need a guard on route.

I have first modified your getInfo service to return a **Promise**

```
  getInfo(titel: string, type: string) {
    return this.http.get(...).toPromise()
      .then( data => {this.obj = data; return data; });
  }
```

I have created a **guard service** and implemented `CanActivate`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AppGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private srv: MyserviceService) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.srv.getInfo("The Beatles", "artist")
      .then(() => return true; })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        return false;
      });
  }
}
```

Modified routing to implement **canActivate**:

```
{ path: "hello", component: HelloComponent, canActivate:[AppGuardService] }
```

You can see the whole stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nazeby

**Update:**

However, if the use case needs only one navigation, you can modify the `navigate` function which now gets the data from service as a Promise and can skip the app-guard service and CanActivate

```
  navigate(){
    this.srv.getInfo("The Beatles", "artist").then(
      () => this.router.navigate(["/hello"])
    )
  }
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

you can use async pipe :

in your ts file:

```
data$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.data$ = this.service.getResourceUrl(url);
}
```

and in html:

```
{{(data$ | async)?.text}}
```